# Is there a way to store password encrypted data along with a expiration date?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, password-encryption

I want to store some data in a password encrypted file. The file should contain:
1) Expiration date of the data
2) The data itself
The expiration date does not necessarily need to be encrypted, but needs to be secured from tampering (eg. the whole file can be signed).

Is there a way to do it using some well defined cryptographic format using OpenSSL ?
I'm only interested in doing it programmatically in C (preferably using OpenSSL API, e.g. EVP_* and friends), executing processes, scripts, Java, .NET, Python and the like are out of the question.

P.S.
I am very familiar with OpenSSL API, but somehow I could not find any good and (at least relatively 'clean') solution for this problem.

Comment: I think I found the right solution: PKCS#12 format is the closest thing to what I need.

Comment: There is a much lighter weight solution to the problem: is is called [AEAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AEAD_block_cipher_modes_of_operation). Unfortunately, there are only patches available for openssl. Of course, you would need the password to verify the expiration date.

Comment: As a separate comment, don't forget to use PBKDF2 or bcrypt to create the secret key. I would advise against using the password directly, at least hash it with a salt if those algorithms are not an option.

Comment: Wait a second, isn't PKCS#12 a key container? Don't you mean CMS (previously PKCS#7)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question. You have to digitally sign the entire file including the expiration date, in order to protect the authenticity of the expiration date, even from users who have access to the password that can be used for decrypting the actual data.

Generate e.g. a RSA key pair you use for signing the encrypted file. The users who decrypt the file should be given access to both the RSA public key and the password.

There are obviously a few caveats with such a scheme. For instance, adding a digital signature will not prevent the users from simply ignoring either the expiration date, the digital signature, or both.